# Test SPM Package using optimization flag

Tags: swift, xcode, xctest, swift-package-manager

I'm trying to test my swift package which relies on [`CryptoKit`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cryptokit) (`SHA256` hash is very slow using `debug` config), and I would like to run the tests using optimization flags.

Using `Xcode 11.4 Beta` and macOS Catalina `10.15.3 (19D76)`. From the terminal, calling

```sh
swift test -c release
```

results in error:

```sh
error: module 'MyCoolPackage' was not compiled for testing
@testable import MyCoolPackage
```

So apparently I cannot use optimization flag by using the `config` named `release` (but we can can use `-c release` for the `swift run` command).

## Without create a `.xcodeproj` file, can I run test with optimization?

Sure, I can generate a project file, but I don't want to do that... Can we run tests without the project file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The magic terminal command is: `swift test -Xswiftc -O`